# Concurrency - going back to main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been experimenting with threads recently. My experiments raised a question I'd like you to answer to confirm my understanding.

If I have this set of classes:

```
public class HelloThread implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
        doSomething();
        doSomethingMore();
        andSomethingMore();
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        // print something
    }

    public void doSomethingMore(){
        // print more
    }

    public void andSomethingMore(){
       HelloThreadExtension helloThreadExtension = new helloThreadExtension();
       helloThreadExtension.doSomethingWithExtension();
    }

}

public class HelloThreadExtension {

    public void doSomethingWithExtension(){
        // do something more advanced than printing
    }
}
```

And then if I will start the `HelloThread` thread, `doSomething()` and `doSomethingMore()` runs in newly separated thread, but `andSomethingMore()` will run back in the main thread, since `HelloThreadExtension` does not `implement Runnable` or `extends Thread`?

OR

Is it actually that it runs in the separate thread that was started once `HelloThread` `.start()` was called?

Regards,
Bob

Comment: Your whole run method will run in new created thread, and thread that will invoke it will go further with its own logic. You can use join to stop thread until another will stop executing, but any method inside thread won't be executed in thread that invoked it. I hope that helps

Comment: `andSomethingMore` will run in the same thread. Add `System.err.printLn(Thread.currentThread().getName());` to print the current thread's name as proof.

Comment: And for the record: you **absolutely** want to put @Override on any method that you write down that you think should override something.

Comment: Do you have any reason and experiences in terms of methods and behaviours that should be concurrently processed (and they're all in .run() method) where half of them is clearly executed in paralel but at some point it appears to go back to being sequential?

Comment: @Up: I can clearly see it logs. Half of run method works nicely and logs come from different threads, but at some it appears only one of them works and the other wait in queue. It gets sequential.

Answer (score 1):

All the code called inside the run method will run in a new thread, and after finishing the execution it will return control to main thread to continue with the code execution.

You can see it by debbugging the code and adding one breakpoint before the Thread.start call and other inside the run method of the Runnable instance. I think doing this debugging exercise will help you to understand how threads works inside the JVM.

Hopes this helps

Comment: Either I'm misunderstand you or this isn't quite right.  The code inside the run method will be run in parallel with the main thread.  The way this is worded it sounds like you're saying the run method will block until its work is done and then return control

Comment: "and after finishing the execution it will return control to main thread to continue with the code execution".  This part is not true unless the main thread explicitly blocks (via thread.join()) to wait for the thread to finish; otherwise main thread just continues on executing without any regard to the other thread.  The rest of the answer is correct.